# Influence on a particular Div only when it is within a specific Div

Tags: css

I have a div called ".grid-1grid-col" that affects all sorts of parts of the site. And I want that when he will be in a specific chip set him other rules. Is it possible? How?

I tried to do this:

```css
#sec-faq-items .grid-1 .grid-col {
  Some rule....
}
```

Comment: can you please update your code, because this is not enough to understand the problem

Comment: what defines 'to be in a specific chip set'?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space between the two classes:

```css
#sec-faq-items .grid-1.grid-col {
  # Some rule
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I think what you're looking for is a child combinator. You were trying to use a descendant combinator, but it is affecting potentially many more elements than just the one you want.
Instead of using a space, use >

Example:

```
.parent-of-the-div-you-want-to-style > .the-div-you-want-to-style {
  background: red;
}
```

In this way, you are more strict with what you target.